# The console returns an error when trying to install selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

when I enter into the console "pip install selenium" this error appears

```
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\12345\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kg71wbn5\cffi_3a42835c6c3f490995a668102eca9def\setup.py", line 126, in <module>
          if sys.platform == "win32" and uses_msvc():
        File "C:\Users\12345\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kg71wbn5\cffi_3a42835c6c3f490995a668102eca9def\setup.py", line 105, in uses_msvc
          return config.try_compile('#ifndef _MSC_VER\n#error "not MSVC"\n#endif')
        File "D:\soft\MSYS2\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 223, in try_compile
          self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
        File "D:\soft\MSYS2\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 128, in _compile
          self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
        File "D:\soft\MSYS2\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 343, in compile
          self.initialize()
        File "D:\soft\MSYS2\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 246, in initialize
          raise DistutilsPlatformError(
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

already tried to enter " pip install --no-cache-dir selenium" or " pip install selenium --pre" and "pip cache purge". pip version is 23.0.1, python version is 3.10.8.

Answer (score 0):

'egg_info' is a command provided by setuptools.

Make sure you have setuptools installed by running the command

```
pip install setuptools
```

Comment: the latest version setuptools is already installed, also installed (beautifulsoup4,bs4,certifi,charset-normalizer,idna,pip,requests,setuptools,soupsieve,urllib3,wheel)